# Javascript Codeacademy query

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So i built a rock paper scissors game on codecademy and was tweaking it. The thing that i tweaked is that when the user writes an inappropriate choice, the code stops.

**Everything worked but when i write "rock, paper or scissor" it still says inappropriate choice.**

```
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    //tweaking starts here  
    if (userChoice!=="rock") {
        console.log("inappropriate choice");
    }
    else if (userChoice!=="paper") {
        console.log("inappropriate choice");
    }
    else if (userChoice!=="scissors") {
        console.log("inappropriate choice");
    }; 
    // tweaking ends here

    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    } 
    console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

    var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
        if (choice1===choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie!";
        }
        else if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2==="scissors") {
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else {
             return "paper wins";
            }
        }
        else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            }
            else {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
        } 
        else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
        };    
    };    
        compare(userChoice,computerChoice);

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic `if else if` ladder problem.

As mentioned in the Java Tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

> However, once a condition is satisfied, the appropriate statements are executed [...] and the remaining conditions are not evaluated.

In your case, when you enter "paper" or "scissor", it breaks out at the first branch as `userChoice != "rock"`. If you enter "rock", it breaks out at the second branch as `userChoice != "paper"`.

Ultimately it doesn't make it through the `if-else-if` ladder and eventually prints the inappropriate choice message.

In order to validate the input such that the user doesn't enter anything but the strings, "rock", "paper" or "scissor", change your tweaking code as follows:

```
//tweaking starts here  
if (userChoice!=="rock" && userChoice!=="paper" && userChoice!=="scissors"){
    console.log("inappropriate choice");
}
}; // tweaking ends here
```

Always remember:

> Only one branch of the ladder gets executed...!!! In case multiple
>   conditions are true, the branch first encountered alone shall be
>   executed.

Comment: I don't input "rock, paper or scissors". I only input one of those things.

Comment: Thanks! That code worked! I just started learning javascript and i didn't know if we can use multiple conditions in one if statement but it still dosen't end the code if it is an inappropriate choice.I just put the rest of the code in an else statement and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might help you see how your if statement logic was incorrect:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

if ((userChoice != "rock") && (userChoice != "paper") && (userChoice != "scissors")) {
    console.log("inappropriate choice");
} else {
    console.log("appropriate choice!");
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/j66to3x0/2/

Comment: I don't want it to say appropriate choice. It should say inappropriate choice and end the code there.

Comment: I only added that for clarity.  You can simply delete the else.

Comment: -1, this is incorrect code! `("rock" || "paper" || "scissors")` will be evaluated first, effectively becoming "rock", so this only checks whether "rock" was input or anything else. (try paper -> incorrect)

Comment: @doldt:  thanks!  I corrected it here and on the fiddle.